# Remove first matching item in a collection

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given a collection, how can I remove *only* the first item that matches a condition?

**For example, given this collection:**

```
[
  { id: 1, name: "don" },
  { id: 2, name: "don" },
  { id: 3, name: "james" },
  { id: 4, name: "james" }
]
```

Filter out the first result that matches `{ name: "james" }`.

**Result:**

```
[
  { id: 1, name: "don" },
  { id: 2, name: "don" },
  { id: 4, name: "james" }
]
```

Comment: `array.splice(array.findIndex(({ name }) => name === 'james'), 1)` without `underscore.js` at least.

Comment: Don't you mean findIndex?

Comment: @jas7457 derp, thanks

Comment: @PatrickRoberts want to post as an answer? I'll accept it :)

Comment: @DonP why? It's not a valid answer to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using underscore.js **`_.without`** and **`_.findWhere`**

```js
var myarray = [
  { id: 1, name: "don" },
  { id: 2, name: "don" },
  { id: 3, name: "james" },
  { id: 4, name: "james" }
];
var arr = _.without(myarray, _.findWhere(myarray, {
 name: "james"
}));
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Using Lodash  **`_.without`** and **`_.find`**

```js
var myarray = [
  { id: 1, name: "don" },
  { id: 2, name: "don" },
  { id: 3, name: "james" },
  { id: 4, name: "james" }
];


var result =_.without(myarray, _.find(myarray, { name: "james" }));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In the latest version of underscore - 4.17.4, there doesn't seem to be a `findWhere`. Know any alternative in the current version? https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4

Comment: are you using loadash or underscore?

Comment: samething you can use

Answer (score 3):

Are you are looking a solution like this?

Iterate and update an array using `Array.prototype.splice`.

```js
var arr = [
  { id: 1, name: "don" },
  { id: 2, name: "don" },
  { id: 3, name: "james" },
  { id: 4, name: "james" }
];
// loop and remove the first match from the above array
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].name == "james"){
         arr.splice(i, 1);
         break;
      }
  } 
// write into the browser console
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

with Lodash

```
var newArray = _.without(array, _.find(array, { name: "james" }));
```